# Swift: Struct instances not updating view

Tags: swift, xcode, struct, swiftui

The following code is simplified and isolated. It is intended to have a `Text()` view, which shows the number of times the button has been clicked, and a `Button()` to increment the text view.

The issue: Clicking the button does not actually change the Text() view, and it continues to display "1"

```
struct Temp: View {
    
    @State var h = struct1()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                h.num += 1
            }, label: {
                Text("CLICK ME")                
            })
            Text(String(h.num))
        }
    }
}

struct struct1 {
    @State var num = 1
}
```

What's funny is that the same code works in swift playgrounds (obviously with the `Text()` changed to `print()`). So, I'm wondering if this is an XCode specific bug? If not, why is this happening?

Comment: Take the State out of the struct that isn’t a SwiftUI View. It doesn’t belong there.

Comment: @lorem ipsum, this fixed it! thank you! I have zero idea why, though... could you make an answer, and maybe say why this worked?

Comment: The State property wrapper is for use in SwiftUI Views specifically, not just any struct.

Comment: @chuk do you mind accepting the answer? It is the green checkmark below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@State` from the variable in `struct1`

SwiftUI wrappers are only for SwiftUI `View`s with the exception of `@Published` inside an `ObservableObject`.

I have not found this in any documentation explicitly but the wrappers conform to `DynamicProperty` and of you look at the documentation for that it says that

> The view gives values to these properties prior to recomputing the view’s body.

So it is implied that if the wrapped variable is not in a `struct` that is also a SwiftUI `View` it will not get an updated value because it does not have a `body`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/dynamicproperty

The bug is that it works in Playgrounds but Playground seems to have a few of these things. Likely because of the way it complies and runs.